# jquery append to front/top of list

Tags: jquery

I have this unordered list

```
<ul>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way I can prepend to the unordered list so that it ends up like this?

```
<ul>
   <li>ONE</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Notice the "ONE" is added to the FRONT/TOP of the list.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
$("ul").prepend("<li>ONE</li>");
```

Answer (score 40):

Something simple like this ought to work:

```
$("ul").prepend("<li>ONE</li>");
```

Answer (score 9):

use prepend instread of append

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>    
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">Hello</div>
<div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>

$('.container').prepend('<p>Test</p>');
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ for more info.