# Appending item to list with Ajax after post - layout related

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have an activity stream for both users use, and site-wide view. Currently when a user posts an update, I have it displaying a default bootstrap success alert.  I have seen other websites append the new post to the list by sliding down the existing items, and appending the newest post to the top of the list.

I am attempting to do just that, but I am not sure how to add it with all the proper styling.  *(code below)*.  I am tried adding all the `<div>` tags that make up one activity item in my feed, but without success.

**TL;DR** - Is there a way to have ajax look at the current top activity item, clone it, and append it to the top?  It would make the code more dynamic for my use, and avoid having to place CSS inside the `.js` file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('form#postActivity').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $postActivityNow = (this);
        var subject = $('#activity_subject').val();
        var message = $('#activity_content').val();

        var data = {
            'action': 'postAnActivity',
            'subject': subject,
            'message': message,
        }


        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: postAnActivityAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            error: function (response, status) {
                alert(response);

            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    bootstrap_alert.success('Activity Added');
                } else {


                    if (response.data.loggedIn == false) {
                        bootstrap_alert.warning('you are NOT logged in');
                        console.log('you are not logged in')
                    }
                    if (response.data.userExists == false) {
                        console.log(response);
                        bootstrap_alert.warning(response.data.alertMsg);
                        console.log(response.data.alertMsg)
                    }

                }

            }

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use [`.prependTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

```
var newActivity = $( ".activity" ).first().clone();    
newActivity.prependTo( ".parentDiv").hide().slideDown();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VKjNw/2/)

Comment: What if the div I am cloning has multiple divs inside of it.  Can I still clone it and prepend?  I would need to clone the top level div and all children?

Comment: yes you can : [`.clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)  "_The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all of their descendant elements and text nodes._". [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VKjNw/4/)

Answer (score 1):

To clone an element: [jQuery.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
var newItem = $("#myDiv").clone();
```

To append it as first child: [jQuery.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$("#parentDiv").prepend( newItem );
```

Regards,
hotzu

Answer (score 1):

I have already done in the past using $.prepend()

Check this url for more information [jquery append to front/top of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469640/jquery-append-to-front-top-of-list)